# log file of ffmpeg's subprocess STDOUT always empty

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

why is the log file always empty?
I'm just trying to capture the "time=" from ffmpeg, but I need to make sure it captures the output first, which it doesn't.

```
import ffmpeg
import subprocess

input_video = ffmpeg.input("test.mp4") 
audio_stream = input_video.audio
video_stream = input_video.video

output_stream = ffmpeg.output(video_stream, audio_stream, 'test_COMPRESSED.mp4', crf=28, vcodec='libx264', vsync=2)

cmd = ' '.join(ffmpeg.compile(output_stream, overwrite_output=True))
process = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd,
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True
)

while process.poll() is None:
    with open('log.txt', 'a') as log_file:
        for line in process.stdout:
            output_line = line.strip()
            log_file.write(output_line + '\n')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use same code just replace the cmd, the logfile has content

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = 'ls -al '
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        shell=True,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        text=True
    )

    while process.poll() is None:
        with open("log.txt", 'a') as log_file:
            for line in process.stdout:
                output_line = line.strip()
                log_file.write(output_line + '\n')
```

the question is ffmpeg output is not stdout, use stderr instead

```
        # stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        # stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
```

both the two above arg add in Popen is ok.

Comment: you just changed the whole cmd command I'm using, how is that solving the issue

Comment: I mean, you need to check if your cmd get some output, so. you can run it in terminal to check.

Comment: Besides, your output_stream is not known in your code. so others can not run to repreduce your error.

Comment: add args        stderr=subprocess.PIPE or stderr=subprocess.STDOUT in Popen

Answer (score 0):

Turns out ffmpeg outputs to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.